# Regex - Combine "Match" + "Not to Match" Group Patterns. Match a Variety of Sku Number patterns, EXCEPT

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-negation

I've figured out how to match both sets of patterns, but I can't seem to combine it.

Since "not to match" patterns are groups, can I put that entire lookaround between the "match" group?  Why is this not working?

**(?<!not to match group)** (match group) **(?!not to match group)**

**To Match:**
(\w+-\w+)(\w-)*(-\w*)*|(\w+\w*\d{2,})|(#\d{1,})|(([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)-[A-Z0-9]*-*[A-Z0-9]*)

- #A919
- NO-MAR-102
- J-12
- J-005
- BZ06
- BRT05

**NOT to Match**
(\d{2,}/\d{2,})|(\d+\s*(pack|pcs|pc|mm))|((Fine|Medium|Coarse)\s\d{2,}G*)

- 80/100
- Medium 150G
- Non-Wipe
- 3mm

Comment: You need to put **Not to Match Group** before the matching group with a lookahead: `(?!not to match group)(match group)`

Comment: For the example data, you could use a single pattern and match `\b[A-Z]+\d*(?:-[A-Z\d]+)*\b` https://regex101.com/r/X0PZiK/1